# PJSUA Registration is not proceeding

Tags: android, java-native-interface, sip, pjsip, kamailio

Hello fellow developers,

I am developing SIP application using PJSIP library... 
Here is my [code](http://pastie.org/10639521)

And here is my Logcat [log](http://pastie.org/10639518)

**The problem is application is not trying to proceed registration, and no errors at all... (Or I missed something?)**

And log on my Kamailio Server (when my device tries to connect and log stucks nothing happens):

```
22(32406) DEBUG: <core> [ip_addr.c:229]: print_ip(): tcpconn_new: new tcp connection: 192.168.0.150
22(32406) DEBUG: <core> [tcp_main.c:985]: tcpconn_new(): on port 17749, type 3
22(32406) DEBUG: <core> [tcp_main.c:1295]: tcpconn_add(): hashes: 879:4076:3775, 50
22(32406) DEBUG: <core> [io_wait.h:376]: io_watch_add(): DBG: io_watch_add(0x9f8540, 44, 2, 0x7f6cdbbf3948), fd_no=34
```

ps. I tested server with ready client and everything is ok...

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: can you show the code inside of MyAccount class ?

Comment: @azimov here: http://pastie.org/10639978

Comment: seems that PJSIP is trying to register the endpoint, but I can't see any feedback from the registrar server. Can you set 'timeoutSec' to be less (20 or 30 sec) to see what will be returned

Comment: @azimov I have added acfg.getRegConfig().setTimeoutSec(20); Still couldn't connect :(

Comment: @azimov I can provide my Git (Bitbucket) repository on my project to see clear image... if you want :)

Comment: @azimov on client, no errors :( and on server upon [connection](http://justpaste.it/prr5) and upon [disconnect](http://justpaste.it/prr7) (p.s. it seems application hangs on registration, and disconnects only when I manually kill the app)

Comment: i can take a look into your project, if you still haven't solved this

Comment: @azimov No :( Problem is still there... could you please give me your Bitbucket username so I can add you to my private Repo...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved issue...

The problem was in registering PJSIP in another thread... I was using main Thread and initializing connection on OnCreate() event in MainActivity. Which means, after OnCreate() fired and finishes its job, initialization process was getting destroyed before it connects into server...

What I did:

Before:

```
UaConfig ua_cfg = epConfig.getUaConfig();
ua_cfg.setUserAgent("Pjsua2 Android " + ep.libVersion().getFull());
ua_cfg.setThreadCnt(0);
ua_cfg.setMainThreadOnly(true);
```

After:

```
UaConfig ua_cfg = epConfig.getUaConfig();
ua_cfg.setUserAgent("Pjsua2 Android " + ep.libVersion().getFull());
```

Removing those lines makes PJSIP library to create its own worker thread...